# Is there a way to register a new DRM key system to be recognized by browsers eg. Chrome?

Tags: blockchain, drm, widevine

I'd like to create a new kind of DRM system, as sibbling of `org.w3.clearkey`, `com.widevine.alpha` or others. actually Im still figuring out whether it's possible and how to implement it.

The ultimate goal is to have a new DRM system that can lookup for license through blockchain, indeed, the part about key exchange should be hidden from external world. But this assumes I have a smart contract that stores privately these decryption keys related to each media content.

So far, I've been able to only implement clearkey but it doesn't fit my need as decryption keys are exposed in player side. Relying on existing DRM system like Widevine, Playready and others are not an option at all.

I've been searching for another solution unluckily so far, I've asked chatgbt also but the reply is redodant as it suggest to just register the new key with `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess('my-key-system', [{initDataTypes: ['cenc']}])` but this will throw an exception `DOMException: Unsupported keySystem or supportedConfigurations.`

is there any guideline about how to make such an implementation?
critical points are:

- be able to create a new DRM system independant from existing ones, with some specific flows for license acquisition and keys exchange with the media controller
- be able to run it on any browser (even with some few additional actions from user)
- media controller should be able to recognize the DRM system form manifest

```
<ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" value="<The DRM Sys Name>">
```

Answer (score 2):

You may already have seen it but as you are targeting browser's the best place to start is likely the HTML5 Encrypted Media Extension spec:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/encrypted-media/#common-key-systems

It includes this high level architecture diagram:

[image]

The component circled is the Content Decryption Module and this is probably going to be your biggest challenge - each DRM system is usually associated with a particular CDM and that CDM is tightly integrated with the browser.

Browser providers usually have a preferred DRM, generally because a single organisation or company builds both the browser and also a specific DRM system. Integrating a new CDM into an existing browser is not trivial and generally requires cooperation from the browser vendor.

Comment: make sense, so I guess there is way to add such a new DRM system in a browser without a new build of the browser then

Comment: If you take a look through the Firefox discussion groups you will see some discussion and guides on adding widevine CDM to Firefox as it was not originally supported. These may be useful as examples.

Comment: do you have any link to suggest for that?

Comment: These may be useful: https://github.com/i-rinat/gmp-widevine/blob/master/how-to-enable-on-firefox-47.md    and  search for 'CDM' here: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: not gonna happen, especially "be able to run it on any browser".

The best you can do is cram your own DRM/CDM into Chromium and distribute this custom build, but just "navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess('org.me.superdrm'..." won't magically work with any existing browser as they won't know anything about your DRM, obviously.

It's all proprietary black boxes (I'm mean WV, PR, FPS) with the absolute minimum of interoperability, namely AES-128 encryption, that's the only thing they have in common. So if you come up with something new, the browser won't even know how to request a license/decryption key 'cause this part is purposefully not standardized in any shape or form

Comment: thank you for these insights. at this time, we opt-in to build a kind of our own decryption module (not working exactly the same, only the idea on top of it) then wrap it in a WebAssembly module. it's not a standard solution at all and probably need some cryptoanalysis but for instance it just works as we expected. just need some further investigation for a more secure solution

Comment: Sure, you can implement your own decryption using WebAssembly, WebCrypto or even write an AES decryptor in plain JS, if you fancy it. Just forget about navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess as there's no such thing as custom pluggable DRM

Comment: for now, we don't really need `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess ` since the Drm system is not recognized. instead we process all the decryption step into the wasm module and only send decrypted packets thought MediaSource